# Save values (not formulae) from a sheet to a new workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following function to save a worksheet from a workbook and save it to a separate workbook. However, it is saving the formulas, whereas I would rather just the values end up in the final workbook. How can I modify this so the resultant workbook doesn't contain formulae and just values?

```
Sub Sheet_SaveAs(FilePath As String, SheetToSave As Worksheet)
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    With wb
        SheetToSave.Copy After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Worksheets(1).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .SaveAs FilePath
        .Close False
    End With

End Sub
```

Using the link kindly provided I tried this, but to no avail:

```
Sub Sheet_SaveAs(FilePath As String, SheetToSave As Worksheet)
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    With wb
        SheetToSave.Copy After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Worksheets(1).Delete
        .Worksheets(1).Copy
        .Worksheets(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        .SaveAs FilePath
        .Close False
    End With

End Sub
```

but I get an error on the pastespecial line??

Answer (score 2):

```
.Worksheets(1).Copy
```

This copies the sheet itself and does not relate to `PasteSpecial`. You could use:

```
.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy
```

or similar. For example, `Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy`.

I assume it should be `Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)` though.

In the following I am using `SpecialCells` to identify only the formulas in the worksheet, and setting `rng.Value = rng.Value` to convert these to the results of the formulas.

```
Sub Sheet_SaveAs(FilePath As String, SheetToSave As Worksheet)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngFormulas As Range, rng As Range

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    With wb
        SheetToSave.Copy After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
        Set ws = .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Worksheets(1).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        With ws
            Set rngFormulas = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            For Each rng In rngFormulas
                rng.Value = rng.Value
            Next rng
        End With

        .SaveAs FilePath
        .Close False
    End With
End Sub
```

You will need to add some error handling code, to handle the case where there are no formulas in the copied worksheet. (Array formulas may also need to be accounted for.)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to copy the values is to do it in 2 steps:
Copy the sheet, then replace the formulas with their values

After:

```
.Worksheets(1).Delete
```

in your original code, add the lines:

```
With Range(Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).UsedRange.Address)
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

The `.value=.value` is telling excel to replace every value with the value that is currently being displayed, so all formulas will be replaced with their calculated value

Comment: AND... Sean beat me to "UsedRange" by a minute! ;)

Comment: There is no need to extract the Address, just `.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).UsedRange.Value = .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).UsedRange.Value`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, answer was starting to look a complete mess, so deleted it and started again. I've written this - it appears to work fine when I tested it - you just need an extra line to save any resulting spreadsheet. :)

```
For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
    Cell.Copy
    Cell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Next
```

Comment: How easy is it to incorporate the paste special in to what I already have? I have done copy and pasting by value before- the reason for my confusion is that my code above doesn't currently do any pasting.

Comment: I think you have to paste each cell - maybe try using a nested loop?